# problems in printing each digit of a number in erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to make a program that will read in a number and then output every digit of that number in a list. However, most of the things look fine until I try with number 8 and 9. The program only output `\b` `\t` instead. 
if the input number contains 8 or 9, and in the same time there are other numbers, for example `283`, it will print normally. Otherwise if there is only 8 or 9, such as`8`, `99`, then it will give me that binary representation of 8 and 9 (if I remember correctly). 
My program is as below:
`digitize(0)-> 0;`
`digitize(N) when N < 10 -> [N];`
`digitize(N) when N >= 10 -> digitize(N div 10)++[N rem 10].`

Comment: You don't need the first clause, and in fact it returns the wrong result if you pass a 0: `digitize(0)` should return `[0]`, but because of that clause it returns `0`. If you drop that clause and keep the other two, you get the right answer. Also, you don't need a guard on the last clause, since the previous `N < 10` already leaves everything greater than or equal to 10 for the final clause.

Comment: @SteveVinoski yup, thanks for the tips! =)

Comment: nice, I had the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number in list printed as "\f"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857704/number-in-list-printed-as-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns the expected list, but the shell shows lists of numbers which are ASCII-codes of characters as strings (because that's just what strings *are* in Erlang; there's no special string type). You can see it by just entering `[8, 8]` (e.g.) at the prompt and disable this behavior by calling `shell:strings(false)` (and `shell:strings(true)` when you need the normal behavior again).

Answer (score 3):

Strings in Erlang are no separate type but a list of numbers.  List printing has a heuristic to detect when it might be a string.  If it thinks it's a string it will be printed as such. \b is the backspace character and \t is the tab character which are ASCII codes 8 and 9

See also:

- [Description what a string means](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66749)
- [Erlang escape sequences](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id66877)
- [Explanation of this in LYSE](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists)