# Addition 2 Matrix Erlang

Tags: matrix, erlang, addition

I have a question 
I want to do the addition of 2 matrix by row in erlang, I'm trying to apply the code for Haskell:

```
add :: Num a => [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
add = zipWith $ zipWith (+)
```

I did something like this:

```
add([[]],[[]]) -> []
add = zipWith $ zipWith (+)
```

but it get's an error, with the $, I'm really confused. How can I do this in erlang?

And works in this way:

```
  add([[ 1, 2 ],[ 3 , 4 ]] , [[ 4 , 5 ],[ 6 , 7 ]] ).
```

> Result:

```
[[ 6, 8], [ 10, 12]]
```

Comment: How are define your matrixes?

Comment: That's not even vaguely Erlang syntax. Can you give more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: The matrixes is by row, an input from the console, something like this: add([[1,2],[3,4]],[[4,5],[6,7]]). Which is matrix A (1 2) (3 4) Matrix B (3 4) (4 5)

Comment: so, your Q split into 2 part - extracting rows from matrix (list) and write elementwise sum into new one, right?

Comment: Yes, Is that I was planning on add the first list add with the second one, using something like map, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: so let's start solve first part - write function s_print/2 which take as arguments 2 matrix and print corresponding to adding rows. After that - write function sum/2 which take 2 list and return list with elementwise sum. And after that you need just union this two function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the direction translation of your Haskell function to Erlang:

```
add(Xss, Yss) ->
  lists:zipwith(fun(Xs, Ys) -> lists:zipwith(fun(X, Y) -> X + Y end, Xs, Ys) end, Xss, Yss).
```

`(+)` becomes `fun(X, Y) -> X + Y end` and since Erlang doesn't have anything like the `$` operator or automatic partial application of functions, we need to name all arguments and explicitly pass them to `lists:zipwith`.

It works as expected:

```
1> a:add([[1,2],[3,4]],[[4,5],[6,7]]) == [[5, 7], [9, 11]].
true
```

Comment: Thanks, but How can I retrieve the result:   add([[ 1, 2 ],[ 3 , 4 ]] , [[ 4 , 5 ],[ 6 , 7 ]] ).  RESULT [[ 6, 8], [ 10, 12]]

Comment: Your Haskell code returns the same value as my answer. Why should it return `[[6, 8], [10, 12]]`?

Comment: It has a mistake, I test it, but I do not why it does not print the second part. a:add([[1,2],[3,4]],[[4,5],[6,7]]).
RESULT: [[5,7],"\t\v"]

Comment: In Erlang, `"\t\v" == [6, 7]`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32670978/320615 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
1> shell:strings(false).            
true
2> AddRow = fun(X, Y) -> lists:zipwith(fun erlang:'+'/2, X, Y) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.99386804>
3> Add = fun(X, Y) -> lists:zipwith(AddRow, X, Y) end.             
#Fun<erl_eval.12.99386804>
4> Add([[1,2],[3,4]],[[4,5],[6,7]]).                               
[[5,7],[9,11]]
```